# Gmaps set marker position by name

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps

Is it possible to set the position of a marker using keywords.

Because the regular way of setting the position of a marker is this:

```
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new GMap.NET.PointLatLng("47.101343, 2.707210"), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
```

But I don't want to set the position using Coordinates.

It is possible to set the gmapControl position with keywords like this:

```
gMapControl1.SetPositionByKeywords("Weert, Netherlands");
```

But is this also possible when positioning a marker?

Answer (score 0):

Use Geocoding in order to accomplish your goal (always refer to the documents priory) : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Fiddle example (write you address in the search box): http://jsfiddle.net/ackzell/t0e7fma0/

Code example (JS):

```
function codeAddress()
{
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```